# Looking for a suitable LMS for building an online education institution

Tags: cloud-service

I'm looking to open a K12 virtual school/education system to run on the education system/syllabus here in Kenya. It has to be a dedicated system to our e-institution, no ads running on the system and completely branded to us. A system that is not only about building courses and making them available to the public, but has a closed student registration. Students are not being registered for courses, but in the school which follows a complete syllabus. Sell courses online - we don't want to sell courses online, but have a school type of system where our courses are available to our students for their particular class. For example, a student in grade 12 should only be having courses related to his grade. Can courses be available on a time-table basis? A system that is not only limited to courses but a student/school management system as well. Any suggestions pls on what wold be a suitable system?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if available for Kenya or what costs would be but the college I work for has been happily using Canvas for 5+ years.  As an admin, teacher, and student I'm really happy with it.  You can get free trial courses to test it with.  https://canvas.instructure.com

If commercial is unaffordable, then check out Moodle.  Free/Open, but you'll end up self-hosting (this may be best if you have issues connecting to cloud services due to poor internet connectivity).

Either of these allow you to manage enrollments, etc. and so should meet your feature needs list.